# which version of jboss i should download?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb

i use eclipse with tomcat 5.5 and jdk 1.6.
i have 2 question
1.which version of jboss is better to download for me?
2.when i go to download page for s special version i see many download items which of them is suitable for me that use windows seven 64 bit with jdk 32 bit for example in blow items in jboss download page

```
Looking for the latest version? Download jboss-osgi-installer-1.0.0.Beta10.jar (15.4 MB) fHome / JBoss / JBoss-4.2.3.GA 
Name Modified Size Status 
{Parent folder 
Totals: 9 Items   299.5 MB  
jboss-4.2.3.GA-jdk6.zip.MD5  2008-07-18 32 Bytes iStats 
jboss-4.2.3.GA-jdk6.zip.SHA-256  2008-07-18 64 Bytes iStats 
jboss-4.2.3.GA-jdk6.zip  2008-07-18 99.7 MB iStats 
jboss-4.2.3.GA-src.tar.gz  2008-07-18 100.4 MB iStats 
jboss-4.2.3.GA-src.tar.gz.MD5  2008-07-18 32 Bytes iStats 
jboss-4.2.3.GA-src.tar.gz.SHA-256  2008-07-18 64 Bytes iStats 
jboss-4.2.3.GA.zip  2008-07-18 99.5 MB iStats 
jboss-4.2.3.GA.zip.MD5  2008-07-18 32 Bytes iStats 
jboss-4.2.3.GA.zip.SHA-256  2008-07-18 64 Bytes i
```

Comment: you do realize that JBoss 7 is the current version, as you can see 4.2.3 is very old!

Comment: i know that..my question is another thing.i say if for example i want download jboss 4.2.3 which of them i should download ?jboss-4.2.3.GA-jdk6.zip.MD5 or jboss-4.2.3.GA-jdk6.zip.SHA-256 or etc???

Comment: the SHA and MD5 files contain the hash of the corresponding archive file, to check the archive's integrity.  You need jboss-4.2.3.GA-jdk6.zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already have the JDK,
get this one `jboss-4.2.3.GA.zip  2008-07-18 99.5 MB iStats`

and for your second question: the above should also help.

FYI. JBoss is already at version 7, so you can safely got to a jboss 5 or jboss 6 version with out a problem; unless ofcourse you have a specific requirement for version 4.2.3.

HTH

Comment: Note that the size difference between `jboss-4.2.3.GA-jdk6.zip` and `jboss-4.2.3.GA.zip` is only 0.2MB, that's why I thought the former is the version compiled for Java 6.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use 4.2.3 - I've had several major issues with it:

- The Hibernate version is buggy and can't be upgraded
- 4.2.3 returns strange AJP packets which can interfere with mod_jk.  See my post @ http://community.jboss.org/thread/153737